A boolean field goes from true to false after some time
I have a Address table which will store the pickup location for a particular user, the user is allowed to have only one defaultAddress, which is a boolean value, true means that particular record for that particular user is the defaultAddress, he is allowed to have only one defaultAddress, the value is being set properly, event the change is visible, but after about 4 or 5 hours the defaultAddress value goes back to false, I have tried to simplify the code and check where else the defaultAddress value is being set but the update code is present in only one function and nowhere else. This is the server action which is responsible for making the defaultAddress


export async function updateDefault(address: Address) {
  // Find the default address for that user.
  try {
    let ogDefaultAddress = await prisma.address.findMany({
      where: {
        userid: address.userid,
        defaultAddress: true,
      }
    });
    
    if (ogDefaultAddress.length > 0) {
      // Use the id of the address for that user to turn the defaultAddress to false.
    let turnOgDefaultAddressFalse = await prisma.address.update({
      where : {
        userid: address.userid,
        id: ogDefaultAddress[0].id
      }, data : {
        defaultAddress: false,
      }
    });
    }
  
    // Use the id you are getting from the argument and make that the new default address
     let newDefaultAddress = await prisma.address.update({
      where: {
        userid: address.userid,
         id: address.id,
      }, data : {
        defaultAddress: true,
      }
     })

     return {
      success: true,
      message: `${address.tag} is the new default warehouse`
     };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Line 466 ', error);
    return {
      success: false,
      message: `Error creating a default warehouse`
     };
  }
  
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



